# Que estructura es mas eficiente para implementar el TAD Conjunto en C++

Tags: c++, c

tengo que implementar ciertas especificaciones del TAD Conjunto, el cual es un conjunto de naturales ordenados de forma creciente estricta (sin repeticiones), en la mayoría de funciones y procedimientos a implementar me exigen que cumplan con un tiempo de ejecución en el peor de los casos de  O(n) lo cual no me presenta dificultad, pero en la función, pertenece, me piden un tiempo de ejecución en el peor de los casos de O(log(n)), y aquí fue cuando la estructura que me había planteado en un principio para implementarlo ya no funciona,  que había sido la siguiente:

```
typedef struct conjunto {
    nat elem;
    nat cantidad;
    TConjunto sig;};
```

Esta estructura de lista simplemente enlazada no puede cumplir con la exigencia de tiempo en la función de, pertenece, ya que el tiempo de ejecución en el peor de los casos seria de O(n) y no de O(log(n)) por lo que no sabría que estructura utilizar.
Se me ocurre implementarlo con AVL pero no estoy seguro si es lo mas eficiente.

Por cierto la función a implementar es `bool pertenece(nat x, TConjunto c);`